# how to keep the running total

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

[here is the picture of result of this program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49P9r.png)/My question is about how to keep the running total in loop?
because in my program, the total debt would only based on the last input of the user before the loop gets terminated instead getting the total debt from all creditors

```
/This program is for calculating the total debt
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    float cb,ir,si,totaldebt; //local declaration
    int time,i,sum=0;
    char c[25];
    printf("------------Welcome to Debt Management System-------------");
    printf("\nNOTE:\nDear users,\n\tYou have to enter the creditor's name if you have a debt. But if you have nothing debt left, just enter none");
    for (i=1;i>=1;i++)
    {
        printf("\n%d)Name of the creditor: ",i); 
//the user inputs the name of the creditor
        scanf("%s", c);
        if (strcmp(c, "none") == 0) // condition wherein if the user inputs "none" in the name of the creditor, the loop will terminate
        {
            break;
        }
        printf("Enter your current balance: ");//the user inputs current balance from the said creditor
        scanf("%f",&cb);
        printf("Enter its interest rate: "); //the user inputs the interest rate of of the debt
        scanf("%f",&ir);
        printf("Enter time for the loan: ");//the user inputs month
        scanf("%d",&time);
        si=cb*ir*time/100;//simple interest
        totaldebt=si+cb; //simple interest + current balance
        sum+=totaldebt;
    }
    printf("The total balance you have for now is: %.2f\n",totaldebt); //
    if (totaldebt<=5000)
    {
        printf("\nCongratulations!\n You only have %.2f debt left\n",totaldebt);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nWork harder because out of DEBT is out of DANGER\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Be specific on what you are trying to ask.

Comment: `for (i=1;i>=1;i++)` looks like an awful loop.

Comment: Even if you break out of the loop, you should make something like `while(1)` or `for(;;)` then. `i` might overflow otherwise at some point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're already keeping track of the running total in `sum`.  You just need to use that:

```
float sum = 0;
...

printf("The total balance you have for now is: %.2f\n",sum ); //
if (sum <=5000)
{
    printf("\nCongratulations!\n You only have %.2f debt left\n",sum );
}
else
{
    printf("\nWork harder because out of DEBT is out of DANGER\n");
}
```

Comment: Thanks 
That was a huge help